# Software for teaching/displaying Math

Tags: linux, open-source, math, productivity, latex

I'm currently teaching math online. I don't have a digital pen and everytime I write math equations I usually write it on softwares that are able to support Latex. Currently I use Xournal++, Geogebra, Libreoffice (with Latex plugin).

- The problem with Xournal++ is I have to type it in a box separated from my document. Please look at this picture below as an example. It can update my formula in near realtime which the feature I'm looking for.
  [image]
- Geogebra also has the same problem as Xournal++. Although It's smoother and faster.
  [image]
- Libreoffice is the worst one. I can't see the preview in realtime.
  [image]

So the spesifications for the software:
I can write in main window and the software displays it in an instant. The software doesn't need to compile my text into pdf. Any Web app solution that can do these things is accepted but It has to be able to display pictures. It doesn't have to be using Latex if the software has its own fast way then it's ok. It has to be free and can be installed in Ubuntu. Any help is much appreciated.

-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last year i found this awesome tool called [Mathcha](https://www.mathcha.io/). They describe it as

> Online Mathematics Editor.
> a fast way to write and share mathematics

You can do quite a lot with it. In their `\math` container, you can write math equations in real time using LaTeX keywords. And in their `\diagram` container, you can draw shapes and even plot graphs. Just take a look at their website

Here is the example of what i've done with it. I personally don't like the default font, but you can always change that in the document settings
[image: Example Use]

Comment: Although it has a limitation (It can only create up to 50 docs). This is exactly what I was looking for.